# Get name of route in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, routes

Is there a way to get the name of the route that resulted in the controller method being invoked?

So, in my startup.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "en-test",
    template: "en",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

And in my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{ 
    //below returns the template "en" not the name "en-test" which I want
    var routeName = RouteData.Routers[1].ToString()

    return View();
}
```

As you can see above I have tried to go through the available options I have through inherited Controller class. I can't seem to find anything that gives me what I want. Maybe there's another way?

When debugging I do see a `Name` property. But this is not accessible. So perhaps I'm missing a cast somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to cast to [`(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteBase)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.routebase?view=aspnetcore-2.0):

```
var routeName = RouteData.Routers[1];
var name = ((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteBase)routeName).Name;
```